# Design diagrams used for Node/Express and Angular/react apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, visualization

A typical design document for programs in OO languages contains UML diagrams such as class diagram and sequence diagram. What are the best practices of visualizing design for JS based programs? I know JS supports both class and functional styles. Are UML diagrams the standard for programs in JS based frameworks like Express, React, Angular etc? What if only functions are used and no classes?
If not UML, what are the other design visualization methods used?

I would appreciate if anybody could point me to some well documented design for JS based applications.

Comment: I think you will need to narrow your question if you don't want it getting closed as mostly opinion-based.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I am looking for industry standards. For Ex. UML class diagrams are industry standard for OO designs. I assume developers use some form of design visualization for JS based applications. what are the frameworks and diagrams used? I have no experience  in this field. So trying to learn from experienced JS developers. I appreciate your suggestion on how to narrow down the question

Comment: I tend to think generally "Best Practices" are mostly opinion-based.  I haven't used UML for nearly twenty years (well, except for sequence diagrams), and have architected and designed OOP, FP, and hybrid systems.  I haven't found the need for a pattern language for diagrams, instead using whatever seems handy at the moment.